# ETH vs ETC on Dwarfpool and Poloniex?

Tags: mining, exchanges, mining-pools, ethereum-classic, poloniex

Noob miner here,

Does anyone mining on Dwarfpool know if they have updated to the forked code (ETH), or are we still mining Ethereum classic (ETC)? I currently use Poloniex as my intermediary wallet and they launched the ETC as a separate wallet address.

If i am mining on dwarfpool and the account is pointing to my ETH wallet but we are mining ETC will I loose this mined ETH in the transfer process?

Comment: Your old Dwarfpool linked adress will bring new ETH in Poloniex. ETC got a new adress...

Answer (score 0):

I mine with dwarfpool and they are on the latest Ethereum chain.

Dwarfpool will send ETH to your polx ETH wallet address.